# How to assign app.user data to SonataAdminBundle SideMenu

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata, knpmenubundle

I'm trying to dynamically assign menu items in the SonataAdminBundle SideBar menu based on data from the logged in user such as app.user.id

Do you have any idea how to do that ?

david

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ROLES to the user so you can manage the menus

[sonata-symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/security.html)

Comment: My point is not to hide/show sonata menus regarding roles, it is about generating links for a specific user like instead showing a list of user for fosuser, i want to generate the user admin profile page link for that particular user logged